# How do I prevent git push-to-deploy from creating "refs" folder above working tree?

Tags: git

I currently have the following simple "push-to-deploy" strategy in a post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    path="/var/www/html/$branch"
    mkdir -p $path
    git --work-tree=$path checkout -f $branch
    chmod -R g+w $path
    chown -R apache $path
done
```

And what this is doing is creating a `/var/www/html/refs` folder, in addition to the desired `/var/www/html/{branch}`.

The refs folder looks like this:

```
/var/www/html/refs
    heads/
        branch1/
        branch2/
        etc...
```

But they are all empty, and deleting them seems to have no negative impact.

Is there a reason Git is confused about creating this folder?

I have tried supplying `--git-dir` and makes no difference.
I have the latest version of Git on CentOS 7.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. You got to the edit before I could!

Answer (score 2):

While I can't reproduce your problem, the approach in this hook just seems *wrong*:

```
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
```

This part is good so far...

```
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
```

This appears to be an attempt to strip off `refs/heads/`.  While that's a fine goal, this is certainly the wrong way to do it, because if the ref does not being with `refs/heads/` (e.g., if someone is pushing `refs/notes/commits` or `refs/tags/v1.1`), you will get some sort of shortened name (`notes/commits` or `v1.1`) that is *not* a branch name and thus probably should not be deployed.

Based on what is actually happening, it seems that you are not getting shortened names at all (which is what I cannot reproduce here).

```
    path="/var/www/html/$branch"
    mkdir -p $path
    git --work-tree=$path checkout -f $branch
    chmod -R g+w $path
    chown -R apache $path
done
```

The rest of this would be OK as long as `$branch` expands to a *branch* name, with several further issues that I will get to in a moment.  (It also assumes that the deployment script is running as the super user, which may not be a great idea, but that's a different problem entirely.)

One way to repair this particular problem is to make sure that `$branch` really is a branch name, by changing the top of the loop:

```
    case $refname in
    refs/heads/*) branch=${refname#refs/heads/};;
    *) continue;; # not a branch name, skip entirely
    esac
```

That is, check whether the reference is in fact a branch name, and if not, skip over it.  If it *is* a branch name, the name of the branch is the refname with `refs/heads/` stripped off the front.

---

This leaves the remaining issues.  The first is this line:

```
    git --work-tree=$path checkout -f $branch
```

The *index file* that git will use while checking out `$branch` into a work tree at `$path` is the default index file, which is `$GIT_DIR/index`.  Suppose that we then push two different branches, either simultaneously or one after the other, such that the loop runs twice (either because there are two names to update, or once for each push).

On the first trip through the loop, suppose `$branch` is `master`.  We will `git checkout ... -f master`, which will use the index file contents as a cache to be smart about what does and does not need to be checked-out into the work tree at `$path`, which in this case will be `/var/www/html/master`.

On the *second* trip through the loop, suppose `$branch` is `develop`.  We will `git checkout ... -f develop`, which will use the *same* index file (which now matches the `master`-branch commit just checked out) to decide what files, if any, should be updated in the work tree at `$path`, which is now `/var/www/html/develop`.

If most of the files are *the same*, git may not bother checking them out at all, since it knows from the cache that they are already there.  (The exact details vary by both OS and file system, but git tries to use directory time stamps to optimize the check-out process.  As long as the `develop` directory and its subdirectories is not too new, this will bite you eventually.)

There are two ways to work around this, only one of which I have ever tested myself.  One is to remove the contents of the work tree first, so that it is all new, git can see for sure that nothing is cached, and git has to create everything anew.  (This method has the advantage of being easy to implement, but the disadvantage of being a bit slow.)  The other is to use a per-branch index file, so that git's cache data actually matches the checkout.

Using a per-branch index, you need to find a place to put the index that will be safely separate from every other branch.  You could put it into the work-tree (in a `.git` directory there, for instance), or put it in a parallel directory outside both the repository and the per-branch tree, or create a directory within the git repository to hold them.  Remember to account for the possibility that a branch is named `ab/cd`, and also that said branch is deleted and then a new branch named `ab` is created.

This brings us to the second issue, which is that very same possibility.  Suppose branch `ab/cd` exists for a time and you `mkdir -p /var/www/html/ab/cd`.  Then suppose that branch is *deleted*.

First, we'll leave the work tree `/var/www/html/ab/cd` behind.  Maybe this is even correct, but maybe not.  Second, when the deletion push occurs, we will attempt to `git checkout ... -f ab/cd`, which will fail because branch `ab/cd` is gone.  Finally, if yet another new branch `ab` is created, we will `mkdir -p /var/www/html/ab` (which is OK as far as it goes) but fail to remove `cd/` from there.

To fix all of these, we need to either totally rule out branch deletion, or handle it somehow.

We can achieve the former by only deploying "blessed" branch names.  This also solves most of our remaining issues: in fact, we will not even need the `mkdir -p` at all, since whoever is setting up the script can do the `mkdir` at the same time they bless the branch name.

To do this, instead of deploying arbitrary branch names, we can just match the blessed ones.  There are a lot of ways to do that but the simplest is to replace our `$refname` cases with something like this:

```
case $refname in
refs/heads/master) branch=master;;
refs/heads/test) branch=test;;
*) continue;;  # master and test are the only blessed branches
esac
```

Now, even if branch `master` or `test` is deleted, we keep the html tree.  (We should still fix the checkout issue by not attempting to check them out if they were deleted.)

Let's look at another option, which is auto-deleting deleted branches and auto-creating newly created branches.  This is where we get to explore setting a per-branch index file as well, and shows how to avoid checking out a deleted branch.

A branch is being *created* if `$oldrev` is 40 `0`s.  It is being *deleted* if `$newrev` is 40 `0`s.  (At most one of these is allowed, and for normal updates, neither will be the special NULL-sha1.)

So, now we might do this instead (warning, untested):

```
NULL_SHA1=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 # 40 0's

while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    case $refname in
    refs/heads/*) branch=${refname#refs/heads/};;
    *) continue;;
    esac

    path="/var/www/html/$branch"
    pbdir="$GIT_DIR/perbranchindex/$branch"
    case $oldrev,$newrev in
    $NULL_SHA1,*)
        # new branch: create path and index file
        mkdir -p "$path"
        mkdir -p "$pbdir" && : > "$pbdir/index"
        ;;
    *,$NULL_SHA1)
        # deleted branch: remove path and index file
        rm -rf "$path" "$pbdir"
        continue # and skip checkout too
    *)
        # normal update
        ;;
    esac
    GIT_INDEX_FILE="$pbdir/index" git --work-tree="$path" checkout -f "$branch"
    chmod -R g+w "$path"
    chown -R apache "$path"
done
```

**Edit**: I turned the above into a general deployment script and decided that not creating the index file directory and deployment path on updates is a bug.  The deployment script (still mostly untested and with debug turned on) is [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/git/deploy.sh.txt).